# How can I determine how directories/filesystems have been mounted?

Tags: filesystems, mount, automounting

I have access to a VM which on a different network at work using NIS. (Debian by the way)

This VM has about 10 extra /directories in / when I log in. They do not exist on that VM alone, they are publicly hosted directories (I know where to access some of them via Windows shared drives as well).

I'm trying to figure out how to create the same directory structure on my own VM where I have root access.

But I've been unable to figure out how these were mounted. I searched the config and init files as best I could and didn't find anything useful, just some dead ends. Using the mount command I only see 3 mounts listed, all in deeper /sub/directories (ie. /home/myuser). Any ideas?

Comment: If they don't show up in `mount` output then they're not mounts per se.

Comment: `cat /proc/mounts` is more accurate than `mount` - `mount` reads `/etc/mtab` which might not be up to date.

Comment: Btw. depending on your VM setup (e.g. if you are using containers) you may have no way to access/determine how the directories where mounted if they are not listed in `/proc/mounts`

Comment: The output of your 'mount' command, and/or the contents of the /proc/mounts file (for the purists) would help.   They 'extra' directories could be fuse mounts, NFS, samba ... although in my experience, ALL of those show up in the 'mount' or '/proc/mounts' output.  But the output would help.

Comment: Note that mounting itself doesn't create directories: you mount a filesystem on an existing directory (which is normally empty). Post the output of `cat /proc/mounts`.

Comment: In /proc/mount, automounted stuff is not listed in any detail. I used "ypcat {map names in auto.* files}" command to print out the auto mounted stuff. There were tons of lines. I haven't yet figured out how to copy this to my own VM.